# Do I need F-statistic and t-statistic for regression if I have the p-value?

Tags: regression, t-test, p-value, f-statistic

I am running a simple linear regression, and was wondering whether I need to use the F-statistic and t-statistic to:

- prove the significance of my results
- run a two-tailed hypothesis test on the coefficient of the explanatory variable

given that I already have the p-value of the explanatory variable's coefficient.

Comment: P-value should be enough to judge appropriate conclusion of a test of hypothesis. Most statistical software also provides test statistics in output. Different software packages have various conventions. (Even R, among the most parsimonious, gives both test statistic and P-value.) Some print almost every conceivably relevant number, some just the bare minimum. Also varying numbers of decimal places reported

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! What about the reliability of my regression model? The p-value cannot be used to determine this yes? That is only done with the significance of my F statistic right?

Answer (score 1):

I am with you that the test statistics are useful largely because they imply (or at least suggest) p-values, so if you already have the p-value, working backward to get the test statistic does not make much sense. You have some sense of what p-value constitutes statistical significance (such as the venerable $p<0.05$). Compare your p-value to that threshold. If your calculation of what constitutes statistical significance is in terms of a threshold for the test statistic, that calculation came by using some $\alpha$ threshold for the p-value (such as $\vert t\vert>2$ to indicate significance at the $0.05$-level), so you can use that $\alpha$ to make sense of your p-value and determine its significance.

Whether or not such dichtomous thinking about significant/insignificant is good for science is a separate issue, and most statisticians would say that it is not. However, if that is how you want to proceed, you have the needed information in the p-value.

**EDIT**

[An exception is if you are using instrumental variables, where estimator bias appears to be a decreasing function of the $F$-statistic.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/610836/247274)