# Why would an instrumental variable have its strength measured by an F-statistic?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, econometrics, instrumental-variables, f-statistic

A typical "rule of thumb" for instrumental variables is that an F-statistic of ten or higher indicates a strong instrument. This is mentioned in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/184803/247274) Cross Validated post, which contains a reference to a [Stock, Wright & Yogo (2002)](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/epdf/10.1198/073500102288618658?needAccess=true#.Y_eMzXbMLMZ) article (that I cannot access), and I have seen such a value mentioned in primary literature that uses instrumental variable regression.

Why consider an F-statistic at all? Unless the null hypothesis in the first stage of the two-stage least squares regression is absolutely true (which is probably is not), the F-statistic can be driven as high as is desired by increasing the sample size. The F-statistic is both a measure of the strength of the relationship and the sample size, rather than the measure of relationship strength that instrumental variable regression regards it.

This seems tantamount to looking at the t-statistic (or p-value) of a t-test, seeing how large (or small) it is, and concluding that the effect must be gigantic. **NO!** That's what the [effect-size](/questions/tagged/effect-size) quantifies. That practitioners often make the mistake of using p-values to measure effect size does not change the fact that it is a mistake.

So what's with looking at the F-stat for instrumental variable regression?

**CITATION**

Stock, James H., Jonathan H. Wright, and Motohiro Yogo. "A survey of weak instruments and weak identification in generalized method of moments." Journal of Business & Economic Statistics 20.4 (2002): 518-529.

**EDIT**

I heard from some people today that the F-stat threshold for a “strong” instrument is becoming $100$ instead of $10$. This makes me wonder if, with how easy it tends to be to get larger data sets than used to be available, it is way too easy to get $F=10$ despite a small effect size, prompting the bump up to $100$.

Comment: I think the asymptotics used to derive the formula rely on both the sample and the number of weak instruments going to infinity, so the F statistic does not go up. Pages 207-208 in Mostly Harmless mention this.

Comment: Two comments: (1) not only does it _seem_ tantamount to a t-test; it _is_, [because t and F test are related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/554130). And (2), F=10 actually hasn't been considered sufficient for calling an IV 'strong', but [rather F=100](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.05058).

Comment: @Durden But why use *any* F-value, when the F-value gets super high for large sample sizes? For instance, compare these `R` simulations, where regression `3` has a much higher F-stat than regression `2` despite lower $R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$. ```set.seed(2023);
N1 <- 100;
N2 <- 1000;
N3 <- 10000;
x1 <- runif(N1);
x2 <- runif(N2);
x3 <- runif(N3);
y1 <- x1 + rnorm(N1);
y2 <- x2 + rnorm(N2);
y3 <- x3 + rnorm(N3);
L1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1);
L2 <- lm(y2 ~ x2);
L3 <- lm(y3 ~ x3);
summary(L1);
summary(L2);
summary(L3)``` Does regression `L3` really indicate a stronger relationship?

Comment: Your observation strikes at the root of what's flawed with frequentist inference: any sharp null hypothesis will almost surely be rejected as $n \to \infty$ because [any point on a continuum has zero measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/338210). In the statistics literature this is known as the Jeffreys-Lindley paradox.

Comment: @ Durden Yes, but not every effect size has to be considered practically significant. In the course of my work and just reading articles (across multiple fields), I have routinely encountered situations where the hypothesis test is screaming out that there is a difference, but when you look at the size of the difference, it is practically the same as the value under the null hypothesis, and we get the tiny p-value (or gigantic F-stat or t-stat) because there are a million observations. Thus, why consider the F-stat instead of RMSE or a function of RNAE, such as (adjusted) $R^2?$ Bounty awaits!

Comment: The 2SLS estimator is consistent but biased and but the bias disappears asymptotically (i.e. in large samples) but is also smaller when the strength of the relationship between the instrument and exogenous regressions is high. The F-stat captures both these relationships.

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty I can get on board with something related to the asymptotic behavior. Can to expand that into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here I expand somewhat more formally on the comment I made earlier, although the arguments here are not complete or fully rigorous (as you will see). This derivation is a more detailed version of the one given on page 207 of Mostly Harmless Econometrics (Angrist and Pischke) (thanks @dmitriy for the reference). The references given on the footnotes of that page should help resolve remaining technical ambiguities. Let us consider the following simple model: the second stage given by

$$ y = \beta x + \epsilon \tag{1}$$

where for simplicity we assume that $x$ is scalar (here compactly represented as a $n \times 1$ vector) and endogenous (i.e. $\mathbb{E}[x_i\epsilon_i] \neq 0$) and the first stage given by

$$ x = Z\Pi + \nu \tag{2}$$

where $Z$ is some $n \times L$ matrix of instruments, and $\Pi$ is a $L \times 1$ matrix of parameters. Suppose that the exogeneity assumption for instruments is satisfied, in that $\mathbb{E}[Z_i \nu_i] = \mathbb{E}[Z_i \epsilon_i] = 0$. Further, suppose that both the error terms are conditionally homoskedastic both separately and together (i.e $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon \epsilon^T \mid X ] = \sigma^2_\epsilon I$, $\mathbb{E}[\nu \nu^T \mid Z] = \sigma^2_{\nu} I $ and $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon \nu^T \mid Z] = \sigma_{\nu\epsilon} I$). The 2SLS estimator is given by

$$ \hat{\beta}_{2SLS} = (x^T P_Z x)^{-1} (x^T P_Z y). \tag{3}$$

where $P_Z = Z(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^T$ is the matrix of the operator that [projects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem) into the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ spanned by $Z$. Substituting (1) in (3), we can write down the bias of the 2SLS estimator as

$$ \hat{\beta}_{2SLS} - \beta = (x^T P_Z x)^{-1}(x^T P_Z \epsilon). $$

Now we can plug in (2) into the above to yield

$$ \hat{\beta}_{2SLS} - \beta = (x^T P_Z x)^{-1}\left[(\Pi^T Z^T \epsilon) + (\nu^T P_Z \epsilon)\right]. $$

Here is the part which I will not completely justify: one can show that the following approximation holds

$$ \begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta}_{2SLS} - \beta] &\approx \mathbb{E}[(x^T P_Z x)]^{-1}\left[\mathbb{E}[\Pi^T Z^T \epsilon] + \mathbb{E}[\nu^T P_Z \epsilon]\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(x^T P_Z x)]^{-1}\mathbb{E}[\nu^T P_Z \epsilon] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[((Z\Pi + \nu)^T P_Z (Z \Pi + \nu) ]^{-1} \mathbb{E}[\nu^T P_Z \epsilon] \\ 
&= \left(\mathbb{E}[\Pi^T Z^T Z \Pi ] + \mathbb{E}[\nu^T P_Z \nu]\right)^{-1} \mathbb{E}[\nu^T P_Z \epsilon].
\end{align}$$
where we have used the exogeneity assumptions on lines 2 and 4. Now we can use trace tricks that are standard in basic econometrics: observe that $\nu^T P_Z \nu $ is a scalar and so equal to its own trace. The trace is also invariant under cyclic permutations of conformable matrices. Further, the trace of a symmetric idempotent matrix like $P_Z$ equals its rank (this can be seen easily by looking at the spectral decomposition of an idempotent matrix $P$ and noticing that the eigenvalues of such a matrix can only be zeroes or ones and then applying the cyclic invariance of the trace operator). These facts help with the following series of computations

$$ \begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\nu^T P_Z \nu] &= \mathbb{E}[\text{tr}(\nu^T P_Z \nu)] \\
&=\mathbb{E}[\text{tr}(P_Z \nu \nu^T)]\\
&= \text{tr} \left( \mathbb{E}[P_Z\mathbb{E}[\nu \nu^T \mid Z]]\right) \\
&= \sigma^2_{\nu}\text{rk}(\mathbb{E}[P_Z]).
\end{align}$$ Similarly, one can show that $\mathbb{E}[\nu^T P_Z \epsilon] = \sigma_{\nu \epsilon}\text{rk}(\mathbb{E}[P_Z])$. Of course, the rank of $P_Z$ is the rank of $Z$ which is just $L$. Or equivalently
$$\text{rk}(\mathbb{E}[P_Z]) = \text{tr}(\mathbb{E}[P_Z]) = \mathbb{E}[\text{tr}(Z(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^T)] = \mathbb{E}[\text{tr}((Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^T Z)] = \mathbb{E}[\text{tr}(I_L)] = L$$

This all helps us show that

$$\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta}_{2SLS} - \beta] &\approx \sigma_{\nu \epsilon} L \left( \mathbb{E}[\Pi^T Z^T Z \Pi] + \sigma^2_\nu L\right)^{-1} \\
&= \frac{\sigma_{\epsilon \nu}}{\sigma^2_\nu} \left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[\Pi^T Z^T Z \Pi]/L}{\sigma^2_{\nu}} + 1\right)^{-1} \\
&= \frac{\sigma_{\epsilon \nu}}{\sigma^2_\nu} \left(\frac{1}{F+1}\right)
\end{align}$$

where $F$ is the population F-statistic from the first stage equation (2). Note that this tells us that if the F-stat is zero, then the bias of the 2SLS estimator reduces to the bias of the OLS estimator given by $\sigma_{\nu \epsilon}/\sigma^2_{\nu}$. More generally, the bias of the 2SLS estimator is in the same direction as the bias of the OLS estimator, but the bias goes down as the the F-stat rises. This makes sense since the 2SLS estimator is consistent under the standard assumptions and so the asymptotic bias should go to zero intuitively as the sample size goes up. But for a fixed sample size, a stronger relationship between the instruments an the endogenous regressions should also reduce the bias. The F-stat term captures both possible ways in which the bias could be reduced.

Comment: I need to go through this in some detail before I can accept it, but this looks like the kind of answer I was hoping to see. If there are no other responses by the time the bounty grace period starts, "@" me here so I can award you the points, which would be warranted for taking the time to write a long answer. (It seems classless not to award the bounty to someone who at least took a shot, and unless this turns out to be some nonsense from ChatGPT (and I don't think it is), the effort should be rewarded, even if my question about IVs remains.)

Comment: The point of the (admittedly tedious) derivation is to simply approximate the bias of the 2SLS estimator and show how the F-statistic is directly linked to the bias. The F-statistic therefore captures both the actual effect size (which you discuss in your post) along with the effect of the sample size, both of which are important in  determining the magnitude of the bias. A less detailed version of my answer is in Mostly Harmless Econometrics.

Comment: I plan to award it to you during the grace period but want to keep it on t he bounty page until then. If I goof up and miss the window to award it, I’ll issue another bounty. I have yet to go through the answer in detail, though, so it’s only a +50 for now instead of the +75 I anticipate giving eventually.